# Skip elements on a condition based in a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list List:

```
List = [-2,9,4,-6,7,0,1,-4]
```

For numbers less than zero (0) in the list , I would like to skip those numbers and form another list.

Example:-

```
List = [9,4,7,0,1]
```

This is a kind of doubt I have, not sure If we can achieve. If it's possible to achieve, can anyone please post here.

Comment: l2 = [e for e in l1 if e > 0] assuming `l1` is the input list and `l2` the output list

Comment: @C.LECLERC l2 = [e for e in l1 if e >= 0]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have many options to achieve that. With a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you can do:

```
my_list = [i for i in my_list if i >= 0]
```

With [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
my_list = filter(lambda i: i >= 0, my_list)
```

**Note:**

In Python 3, `filter()` returns a `filter` object (not `list`), to convert it to a list, you can do:

```
my_list = list(filter(lambda i: i >= 0, my_list))
```

Comment: i >= 0 OP has 0 in the final list

Comment: Whenever you need to write a lambda for `filter()` it should probably be a list comprehension.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks, I personally prefer LC, I just want to show that it is also possible to use `filter()` with one line of code.

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste with complex conditions.  I would still prefer the list comprehension.  If it were really complicated I would probably define a named function locally and use it with `filter()`.  Again though, it's all personal preference.

Answer (score 7):

First use lower case for variable names, second don't use `list` because it reserved name.

Then just do an if inside the list comprehension

```
my_list = [i for i in init_list if i >= 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code here my_list = [i for i in init_list if i >= 0 ] but i had modified it to fit to my use and i would like to say that it can be used like this:

```
for i in [x for x in range(10) if != 3]
```

I used it here to make the program skip a iteration.